# How to cause setting 'position fixed' on navbar not to change the layout of my page?

Tags: html, css, css-position

So, I have a navbar on the top, footer on the bottom and a big image in the center. I placed everything using margin (margin-top: 0 for nav, margin-bottom: 0 for footer and margin: 3% auto for image. The image is centered on my page and everything is allright. However, when I set position of nav bar to fixed, the margin for image seems to count from the beginning of page instead of the end of navbar (it causes my image to overlap with navbar instead of being in between of footer and margin). The only way I know to fix it is making a second, invisible div with the exact same size as my navbar, but I believe it's not the most practical way.

I don't know if putting HTML/CSS code is necessary there, I think I described everything important.
Thanks in advance for help

Comment: You can set ``position: fixed`` to the first child of nav. And in the nav you use ``padding-bottom`` or a fixed ``height`` to supply the extra height. ``<nav><div></div></div>``

Comment: The fixed element is removed from the normal document flow, so your image's margin start from the top of the page

Comment: You should use a container for content between navi and footer. This container should have a margin-top of your navi's height and then it should work perfectly well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `position:sticky`. it works best if you have fixed height of element.

Comment: Didn't know such a thing existed, never seen this in a css position tutorial. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `position: fixed` removes the element from the document flow. One possible solution is to add a container for the content, in your case a container div for the image, and set a fixed top margin or top padding on the container for the height of your navbar.